# How to make a link : chained list and pointer in c

Tags: c, list, pointers, structure, chained

Helle everyone, I'm stuck in a problem for 1 week and I come here..
I have few structures:

```
typedef struct s_task{
    unsigned int id;
    char *name;
}task

typedef struct s_element_task{
    task *t; 
    struct s_element_task *next_element;
} element_task;

typedef element_task* task_list; 

typedef struct s_agenda{
    task_list *task_by_date; 
} agenda;
```

I want to add a task to an agenda but I don't know how to make the link betewwen theses structures..

I start with:

```
task* my_task = malloc(sizeof(task));
```

but that's all..

thank you un advance

Comment: then create s_element_task. add the previously created task to s_element_task.

Comment: Isn't `s_agenda`'s only member `task_list *task_by_date` supposed to be `task_list task_by_date`, without the extra pointer, because the pointer is already in the type for `task_list`? Usually I'd advise not to hide pointers behind type definitions, as it needlessly obscures. But, that is an opinion, and probably not shared by everyone.

Comment: you're write I made a mistake task_by_date don't have a pointer thanks I didn't notice that in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
task* my_task = malloc(sizeof(task)); //  data object
element_task* my_node = malloc(sizeof(element_task)); // node object
my_node.t = my_stask; // node now knows where data is

element_task* next_node = malloc(sizeof(element_task)); // next node object
my_node.next_element = next_node; // "link" to next node in linked list
```

As a side note, I'd make sure to initialize element_task.next_element to NULL so you can tell whether that node HAS a child or not.

Comment: I think the OP also specifically wanted to know how to use the agenda. But see my comment on OP's post about whether or not he wants the double pointer for `task_by_date`.

Comment: thanks a lot but I don't know how to make tha link to add this task to task_list. Is it correct to write : 'agenda *a = malloc(sizeof(agenda); '
`a->task_by_date = my_node ?`

Comment: task_list is already a pointer, so in the definition of the agenda struct it shouldn't be another pointer (it is currently a pointer to pointer)